# Extra bytes 3F received serialport c#

Tags: c#

I am making a project that implies a PIC18F4610 communicating through a Zigbee wireless UART to a USB serial port with a wireless Zigbee module. When I press a button on the PIC it send a 10 byte packet of data (bytes) wirelessly to the other Zigbee module on the USB port.
The packet it sends is 0A 01 80 90 A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0.
If I use on the PC any terminal program like RealTerm I get that exact packet of bytes sent.
However, on my program I get (generally) the following packet: 3F 3F 0A 01 80 90 A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 that includes de good packet sent but two 3F at the beginning (that is, twelve bytes instead of ten that were sent). I could overcome this by program but sometimes it only places one 3F at the beginning and others it slips a 3F between the packet items. No packet items are lost, only 3Fs are added (only one or two) here and there, generally at the beginning.
I have checked the encoding as 3F is when a character is not found for encoding but it seems ok as it does receive F0 for example. 
The serial port is open as it receives the packet sent. It´s configuration:

```
ST.puertoserie.PortName = "COM1";
ST.puertoserie.BaudRate = 9600;
ST.puertoserie.Parity = (Parity) 1;
ST.puertoserie.DataBits = 8;
ST.puertoserie.StopBits = (StopBits) 1;
ST.puertoserie.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

The DataReceived event handler has been defined and fires upon receiving bytes at the serialport.

```
    ST.puertoserie.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RecepcionBytePuertoSerie);
```

The event handler procedure (ST is a global class I have and includes some variables and the serialport):

```
private void RecepcionBytePuertoSerie(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
     while(ST.puertoserie.BytesToRead > 0) {
     ST.rxcadena[ST.rxindex] = (byte) ST.puertoserie.ReadByte(); 
     ST.rxindex++; 
  }

   byte[] kprueba = new byte[ST.rxindex];
   for (int t = 0; t < ST.rxindex; t++) { kprueba[t] = ST.rxcadena[t]; }
   MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(kprueba).Replace("-", " "));   // Display bytes in message box
   ST.rxindex = 0; 
   ST.puertoserie.DiscardInBuffer(); 
 }
```

Any clue on why this is happening? I've tried all sorts of things but no way. Terminal emulator receives correctly. There has to be some underlying reason in the program, etc. that makes this happen. Right now the program only does this with a simple form until I can get serial communication working. The wireless doesn't seem the problem (hidden codes or anything) as the terminal emulator receives exactly what the PIC is sending. Windows doesn't seem to be the problem either as the terminal emulator receives correctly.
Any clues / help?
Paul

Comment: It sure quacks loudly like an encoding problem, but the snippet cannot explain it.  Get ahead by fixing the visible bugs in this code.  You must delete the DiscardInBuffer() call, it randomly throws away data.  And the ST.rxindex = 0 assignment needs to be done correctly, right now it works by sheer accident.  Do so by counting bytes or by adopting a protocol that allows you to always detect the start and end of a message.

Comment: The .NET `SerialPort` class is one of the [buggiest pieces of bad code](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) I've ever had to use.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't - some devices it cooperates with, others it does not.  More than once I've simply had to scrap it and move to a different solution.  It could be that there's something wrong with your implementation, but I've personally gotten to the point with the `SerialPort` class where I've stopped giving it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: At very least, per the link above, try rewriting to avoid using the `DataReceived` event and the `BytesToRead` property.  Where you have to use the `SerialPort` class it's best to put all processing into its own thread and run a loop to service the port synchronously on that thread.  This lets you get around the worst broken bits of the .NET class.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered a very similar problem when communicating with a device using serial RS232 protocol. My software(written in C# using System.IO.Ports) also introduces 3F(ASCII = "?") in the messages received. I solved it by making the same port configurations(Parity, StopBits, ...) as the device needed. My problem was that I was using serialPort.Parity = Parity.Even, instead of Parity.None (as the device was asking).

On other forums(seems a quite often met problem) it says that the problem is the encoding that c# SerialPort Class is using.
To me did not help, but take a look at this link, maybe it helps you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efe127eb-b84b-4ae5-bd7c-a0283132f585/serial-port-sending-8-bit-problem?forum=Vsexpressvb

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers.

Right now I have bridged physically the Tx and Rx pins of the serial port.
The program is working ok. Perfect. I'll update when doing the same with the USB to serial device. Should work ok. If so I'll pass on to the wireless UART devices that for Realterm work just perfect but for C# strange bytes (3F) start turning up. Will update as I don't have much time except at weekends. Right now I have implemented CRC16 checking of packets that works ok.
Why wouldn't whoever did program correctly the serialport class? Or correct it after?
On the other hand, if I write out a protocol to not use `DataReceived` or `BytesToRead`, I would have to create fixed length packets as I will not know when I have finished receiving data as I can't be sure codes in data that could represent end of packet may be corrupted and / or never arrive. Have to take into account that I am receiving "ghost" bytes that haven't really been sent. Also packets could be truncated and not receive all the packet and the thread wait endlessly. Have to think about it for now.
Will update more (most probably problems and not solutions) as I go on.