# C# Serial Port weird issue by receiver

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I implement a Modbus RTU master using .NET serial port. But I have a issue with receiver. And it is so weird. There were always one or more 0x3F bytes at the beginning of receive packet.

E.g I send the request packet

```
0x0A 0x03 0x07 0xD0 0x00 0x02 0xC5 0xFD
```

and expect the receive packet

```
0x0A 0x03 0x04 0x44 0x36 0xC0 0x00 0xE4 0x0D
```

but the real receive packets were always like this

```
0x3F 0x0A 0x03 0x04 0x44 0x36 0xC0 0x00 0xE4 0x0D
```

or

```
0x3F 0x3F 0x0A 0x03 0x04 0x44 0x36 0xC0 0x00 0xE4 0x0D
```

The code I used for receive is

```
 if(SERCOM.BytesToRead > 0)
 {
   int bytestoread = SERCOM.Read(pReceiveBuffer, pReceiveIndex, SERCOM.BytesToRead);
   pReceiveIndex += bytestoread;
 }
```

I guess serial port see the bus idle between the end of request packet and beginn of response packet as something unexpected and make it as 0x3F(? character).

Hardware problem could be ruled out. I scoped and decoded signal under oscilloscope, everything was fine, no noise, baudrate, parity... were fine. And I also tested with qmodmaster and manually with hterm, it works perfectly with both.

Comment: Show the code on the sender side. I suspect you use a wrong string encoding instead of a binary write.

Comment: Sender side is a MCU (exactly it is RP2040). We use the function uart_write_blocking in Pico SDK https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__uart.html#gada6a512414b1113a59725ddfbe23c4a5

Comment: Oh, that's an important information that's missing in the question. I have seen similar errors with broken transceiver chips and wrong use of libraries, but not with this kind of hardware.

Comment: Seem it is a bug in .Net Serial Port. This topic has the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141293/extra-bytes-3f-received-serialport-c-sharp